# How to record and save a video using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have taken the following code from [this website](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem I am facing is that the video is being stored, but I am not able to open it. The video size is about 6KB, but the duration is 0 seconds. How can I fix this?

I did check the other questions similar to this, but none of them solve the issue I am facing.

Comment: if camera gives frame with size `(800, 600)` then you have to write with the same size `(800, 600)` or you have to use CV to resize frame to  `(640, 480)` before you save it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had problem with opening file if I saved frames with wrong size.

If camera gives frame with size ie. `(800, 600)` then you have to write with the same size `(800, 600)` or you have to use CV to resize frame to `(640, 480)` before you save it.

```
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
```

Full code

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1') #(*'MP42')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))

        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Example on GitHub: [furas/python-examples/cv2/record-file](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/cv2/record-file)

Comment: I would guess the 20 frames per second argument value would make the video duration the same as the real duration of the capture duration, only when the loop really makes 20 iterations per second, but not otherwise.

Comment: @matanster - that's right - loop should run 20 times per second to write 20 frames in second - i.e. more or less `cv2.waitKey(int(1000/20))` if there is no extra calculations. But this problem was not part of original question :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I found out after much googling was that the VideoWriter fails silently.

In my case, I didn't have a VideoCapture object, but a list of frames. I followed the guide similar to what you have done, but the problem was that I was passing in the shapes of the array according to what `img.shape[:2]` was giving me. IIRC, OpenCV has a different ordering of the widths and heights than numpy arrays do which was the source of my problem. See below for the comment from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4655)

> As have been stated by @pstch, when creating VideoWriter in Python one should pass frame dimensions in form cv.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, fps, (w, h), ...). And when creating frame itself - in reverse order: frame = np.zeros((h, w), ...)